# Why is it deadlocking

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock

Code from the book "Java Concurrency in Practice" Listing 8.1

Why is the code deadlocking? Is it because the `rpt.call` in `main()` is basically the same thread as that in Executors?

Even if I use 10 threads for `exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);` it still deadlocks?

```
public class ThreadDeadlock {
  ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  public class RenderPageTask implements Callable<String> {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        Future<String> header, footer;
        header = exec.submit(new LoadFileTask("header.html"));
        footer = exec.submit(new LoadFileTask("footer.html"));
        String page = renderBody();
        // Will deadlock -- task waiting for result of subtask
        return header.get() + page + footer.get();
    }
  }

   public static void main(String [] args ) throws Exception {

        ThreadDeadlock td = new ThreadDeadlock();
        ThreadDeadlock.RenderPageTask rpt = td.new RenderPageTask();
        rpt.call();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code doesn't deadlock - the following does:

```
public class ThreadDeadlock { 
    ...     
    public static void main(String [] args ) throws Exception { 
        ThreadDeadlock td = new ThreadDeadlock(); 
        ThreadDeadlock.RenderPageTask rpt = td.new RenderPageTask(); 

        Future<String> f = td.exec.submit(rpt);

        System.out.println(f.get());
        td.exec.shutdown();
    } 
}
```

This happens if you submit several simultaneous tasks to the single thread executor, when the first task is waiting for the result of the following ones. It doesn't deadlock with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)` because `LoadFileTask`s are independent and can share one thread when another one is used by `RenderPageTask`.

The point of this example is that if you submit interdependent tasks to the `ExecutorService`, you should be sure that capacity of the thread pool is enough to execute them with the required level of parallelism.

Comment: I think you should've added that the original code doesn't finish because there's an executor waiting for the new task and one just needs to add `td.exec.shutdown();` as the last instruction of main in order to finish it.